Managing users for ProxySQL
We are looking at adding ProxySQL in front of our database to route reads to the read only database.
We have about 15 usernames and passwords for all our services. I just want to confirm best practise.
Should we add each of these existing usernames and passwords to mysql_users in proxysql and these username and passwords are "passed thru" proxysql?
Or is there one set of usernames and passwords for the app to authenticate with proxysql and another set for proxysql to authenticate with the database?
